# WCF UserNamePasswordValidator Caching

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, .net-4.0

I have looked across the internet with no luck, I am trying to find a suitable way to cache a username and password token on the service side so each time a connection to the service is made I don't have to create a database connection.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class ServiceAuth : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = Repository.Authenticate(userName, password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            // Perform some secure caching
        }
        else
            throw new FaultException("Login Failed");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use caching when validating credentials in C# 4.0 WCF using UserNamePasswordValidator?

If so, can someone give me some clues on how to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if the username/password combination is no longer valid (i.e. no longer in the database)? How would a caching approach handle this situation?

Comment: A web service is stateless. How do you intend to identify your individual clients? Caching seems like a bad idea in this case. I'd rather have the web service issue an authentication token once for the LogOn method and then verify this authentication token on subsequent calls. So it is the client that will store the token and reuse it on subsequent calls. In a similar fashion like Forms Authentication works in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Bernard thats not something I need to consider at the moment. I am simply trying to prove whether or not this is possible and then look at the pro's and con's afterwards

Comment: @AndyClark: It's definitely possible, I'm just not sure whether it's a wise approach.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have been looking and not seen this method anywhere!

Comment: Not seen this method anywhere? Almost all public APIs over the internet that require some forms of authentication use it.

Comment: @Bernard Fair enough if you think its not wise... but how is it done?

Comment: @AndyClark: You could create a singleton class that caches all of your username/password combinations retrieved from the database. If the username is in the cache, retrieve the corresponding password from the cache, otherwise go to the database, retrieve the username/password and then store them in the cache.

Comment: Make sure the cache is thread safe, unless of course your service is only using one thread. Also I'd suggest storing a hash of the username and password in the cache instead of the actual username/password.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to request the super users not to delete the answer as that could help others who wants to find the solution for their issues..!

I have implemented the the following CUSTOM security manager using key-value pair Dictionary collection for caching. Hope this helps

```
public class SecurityManager : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    //cacheCredentials stores username and password
    static Dictionary<string, string> cacheCredentials = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //cacheTimes stores username and time that username added to dictionary.
    static Dictionary<string, DateTime> cacheTimes = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if (cacheCredentials.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            if ((cacheCredentials[userName] == password) && ((DateTime.Now - cacheTimes[userName]) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))// &&  timespan < 30 sec - TODO
                return;
            else
                cacheCredentials.Clear();
        }
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            //cache usename(key) and password(value)
            cacheCredentials.Add(userName, password);
            //cache username(key), time that username added to dictionary 
            cacheTimes.Add(userName, DateTime.Now);
            return;
        }
        throw new FaultException("Authentication failed for the user");       
    }
}
```

Comment: I second your motion: I would like to request the super users not to delete the answers as well ..
Just because some might not see a reason for doing something because of their paradigm of scenarios - does not mean some one does not have a useful purpose for an answer such as yours - which for the time being might be sufficient enough for my purposes. Not everyone is working on the web, Not everyone has a system that will be connected to the internet.